# Parsing an Excel sheet with more than 255 chars using Python 2

Tags: python, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 3 rows that I am parsing using Python2, and exporting the data to a .txt file. The third row is much more than 255 characters, so when the parser hits the end of the 255 column length, it cuts out the rest of the data. Is there anyway to deal with this?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
outf = open('c:\\Python27\\scripts\\saba_parser\\index.txt', 'w')
outf2 = open('c:\\Python27\\scripts\\IMS\\cse_errors.txt', 'w')
wb = load_workbook('c:\\Python27\\scripts\\saba_parser\\Copy of Saba_Views_good.xlsx')
s1 = wb.worksheets[0]


for r in s1:
   name = str(r[0].value)
   if r[2].value == None:
      tail = "None"
   else:
      #info = r[2].value.split("FROM")[-1]
      info = str(r[2].value)
      head, sep, tail = info.partition("FROM")
outf.write(name+','+tail+"\n")
#outf.write(name+','+info+"\n")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you going to let us know how you're reading the file?

Comment: I added the rest of the code. I though I originally did. Apologies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you load the workbook as ["read only"](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html), you could handle the long columns.

Apparently, if the file does not have the dimension properly set, this could lead to trouble

> Read-only mode relies applications and libraries that created the file providing correct information about the worksheets, specifically the used part of it, known as the dimensions. Some applications set this incorrectly. You can check the apparent dimensions of a worksheet using ws.calculate_dimensions(). If this returns a range that you know is incorrect, say A1:A1 then simply resetting the max_row and max_column attributes should allow you to work with the file

Try using this patch to your code

```
wb = load_workbook('c:\\Python27\\scripts\\saba_parser\\Copy of Saba_Views_good.xlsx',read_only=True)
s1 = wb.worksheets[0]
# Only use the next line if s1.calculate_dimensions() does not give you the expected result
# s1.max_row = s2.max_column = None
```

Comment: I added the "read_only=True" and when running it ends up adding nothing to the file, the .txt file was blank...

Comment: Are you closing the file after you finished writing to it?

Comment: In the original code posted, I had no close and it closed correctly. When I added the read_only, it still closes, just adds nothing to the file. If I put a close statement in after the outf.write, it still closes and adds nothing...

Comment: Did you try to print the `name` and `tail` inside the for loop? That way you'll know if the data is actually being read. On the other hand, have you tried using `for r in s1.rows:` instead of `for r in s1:`? The example in the link at least iterates over the rows differently than you do.

Comment: Changing it to s1.rows fixed the issue. Thank you for the help!